# Read the URL in the QGIS Layer's Tooltip

Tags: qgis, tiles, connection, url, xyz-tiles

From a YouTube video, I made a screenshot for the QGIS layer's tooltip that contains URL of the XYZ tiles connection (See attached pic).

[image]

How can I read this URL and re-use it to make the same connection?

> tilePixelRatio=2&type=xyz&url=http://localhost/tile?style%3D7%26size%3D2%26scale%3D1%26z%3D%7Bz%7D%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26v%3D9312&zmax=21&zmin=0&http-header.referer=

---

The challenge for me is how can I read the URL in the QGIS tooltip and use it again to make the same connection.

Could you deduce the original URL from the URL generated by QGIS Layer's tooltip?

---

This is my try to read and deduce the original URL from the generated one.

http://localhost/tile?style=7&size=2&scale=1&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}&v=9312&tilePixelRatio=2

But after I made a connection with this line I didn't get the same captured tooltip from youtube vid. (See attached screenshots)

This is Generated tooltip after I made a XYZ tiles connection with my attempt

[image]

The tooltip captured from youtube

[image]

Note the difference in the generated tooltip's URLs.

What should I change to my URL to get identical generated URL's tooltips?

Comment: The URL contains `localhost` as the source of the tiles. Unless you are on the same network as the creator of the YouTube video, you will not be able to access the same data.